# How to check file info, which is double-clicked in finder, in preferred application? This is for os x

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to implement some application, which is called as preferred app when users double click file of some type (ex. ".test") in finder.

To implement this, I have a question.

**I want to know the file infos in the preferred application which is implemented by me.**

To test this, I make an application.

I only implement a main function which has to print "argc" and "argv".

I register this app as preferred app for ".test" file extension (ex. something.test).

When I double-click "something.test" file in finder, it executed my app and my app printed that argc is "2" and argv are "/Users/appchemist/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp" and "-psn_0_225954"

So, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app usually does not receive the file to open as an argument to its `main()` function.

When you open a file, your app is launched if it's not already running.

Whether it was or wasn't already running, it is then sent an "open documents" (`'odoc'`) Apple Event. The standard handlers for this Apple Event within Cocoa will call your application delegate's `-application:openFiles:` or `-application:openFile:` method, depending on which it implements.

The reason that Apple Events are used rather than arguments to `main()` is precisely because apps need to be able to open documents even when they are already running. Arguments to `main()` are only useful at launch, which is not good enough, so they aren't particularly useful at all for this purpose.

See [Cocoa Scripting Guide: How Cocoa Applications Handle Apple Events – Apple Events Sent by the Mac OS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-BBCCJHBA) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much! "-application:openFile" method is the solution for my work!